# Populate a dropdown list based on the selection of previous dropdown list using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsp

Hi,I have a JSP page with a form containing two drop-down list,

1. the first for showing the country name and
2. the second for showing the states under the corresponding country.

I have a Mysql database contain two tables country and state respectively.

**WHAT I WANT:**

I need to populate the second drop-down from the database using Ajax where the data from the database must be converted to Json object and give response as Json object.Then populate the second drop-down's based on this response Json object.

**ISSUE I'M FACING:**

My problem is that when i select a value in the first drop-down list the second drop-down list is populated with the value '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' instead of showing the corresponding state names.

Somebody please help me to solve this problem.Here is my code that i have done so far

**index.jsp:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"      
"http://www.w3.org /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>AJAX calls to Servlet using JQuery and JSON</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#country').change(function(event) {  
    var $country=$("select#country").val();
       $.get('ActionServlet',{countryname:$country},function(responseJson) {   
           var $select = $('#states');                           
           $select.find('option').remove(); 

           $.each(responseJson, function(index, name) {               
               $('<option>').val(index).text(name).appendTo($select);      
                });
        });
    });
});          
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>AJAX calls to Servlet using JQuery and JSON</h1>
Select Country:
<select id="country">
<option selected="selected">Select Country</option>
<option value="1">India</option>
<option value="2">china</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
Select State:
<select id="states">
<option selected="selected">Select State</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

**ActionServlet.java:**

```
package ajaxdemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class ActionServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public ActionServlet() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,  
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    JSONArray cellarray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject cellobj = null; //new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
    String country=request.getParameter("countryname");  
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
        Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:
                3306/test","root","root");  
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from state 
                where countryid='"+country+"'  ");  
        while(rs.next()){
            cellobj = new JSONObject();
            cellobj.put("id", rs.getString(1));
            cellobj.put("name", rs.getString(3));
            cellarray.add(cellobj);
        }  
        jo.put("arrayName",cellarray);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(jo.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e);
    }



}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why wont you use $select.html(response.html);
then make sure on your server side you output the options of the select

Comment: Could you post the complete json structure that was received from server end

Comment: you can do console.log(responseJson) then check in your browser how it looks like, I believe it should be something like this {['id':'1'],['name':'somename']}

Comment: if i wrote console.log(responseJson) then the second drop-down shows null values

Comment: I think this may be the structure of json that i had received from the server end.   {"arrayName" : [{"id" : "1","name" : "Tamilnadu"},
            {"id" : "2","name" : "Karnataka"},
            {"id" : "3","name" : "Andaman and Nicobar"}]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the type 'json' as the last param of the $.get() function also I think the
way  you use the json is wrong it will be easier if you provide the server json output.

this will work if your json is:

```
 /*
    {"arrayName" : [{"id" : "1","name" : "Tamilnadu"}, {"id" : "2","name" : "Karnataka"}, {"id" : "3","name" : "Andaman and Nicobar"}]}  
*/


    $.get('ActionServlet',{countryname:$country},function(responseJson) {  
        var html;
        var $select = $('#states');  
        $.each(responseJson.arrayName, function(options) {               
         html += '<option name="'+options.id+'" >'+options.name+'</option>';      
        });
     $select.html(html);
    },'json');
```

Comment: hi talsibony,i got null values in the second dropdown if i tried the above code

Comment: I modified the code added responseJson.arrayName this should work now

Comment: -your logic is right,but need to use function(index,value){},value.id,value.name instead of function(options) {},options.id ,options.name

Comment: Why you want to use index? the index is just the loop counter you can add it but still you will have to use .id .name because these are the properties you defined on your server side. I assumed you wanted to get the Id you passed on your server site so it will match for farther use.

Answer (score 0):

**First Point:**
If an alert box is showing [object object]. It's correct only.Because an alert box can show neither a string or this property only.
Instead of using alert box, just try console.log(data);
You can see your data is correctly there. So it's not the problem of your alert box.

**second point**
May be[not sure]
your data is in the following format:-
[
    {
        "map":
            {
                "TARGET_ID":"2020-000001","STATUS":"OPEN","FREQ_ID":"f001","END_DATE":"2020-05-30 00:00:00.0","START_DATE":"2020-05-15 00:00:00.0"
            }
    }
    ,
    {
        "map":
            {
                "TARGET_ID":"2020-000001","STATUS":"OPEN","FREQ_ID":"f002","END_DATE":"2020-06-14 00:00:00.0","START_DATE":"2020-05-31 00:00:00.0"
            }
    }
    ,
    {
        "map":
            {
                "TARGET_ID":"2020-000001","STATUS":"OPEN","FREQ_ID":"f003","END_DATE":"2020-06-30 00:00:00.0","START_DATE":"2020-06-15 00:00:00.0"
            }
    }
]

To solve this issue use my given solution. It will work

```
<script>
function callFunction() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                },
                url: '/Tutorial/abc',
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    array_data = [];
                    target_id = [];
                    var s = '';

                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        array_data.push(value['map']);
                    });

                    s += "<select name='user_id' onchange='onsubmitUser();' >";
                    s += "<option value='' disabled selected>Select your User id</option>";

                    $.each(array_data, function (index, value) {


                        s += '<option value="' + value['USER_ID'] + '">' + value['USER_ID'] + '</option>';

                    });
                    s += '</select>';
                    $('#result').html(s);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```